# Get PDF page coordinates when it is clicked with ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

Tags: angular, pdf-viewer, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

I would like to know if it's possible to get the coordinates of the **PDF page** when the user **clicks** on it.

I need this because I want to send the coordinates to the backend so that they can attach **text fields** in the respective location.

Is this possible to achieve using `ngx-extended-pdf-viewer`? I'm open to using any other PDF viewer library as long as I have a simple way of getting the PDF page coordinates on a user click event.

Alternatively, if there are any libaries that support adding text fields that can be saved into the PDF and later be editable, that would also work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @KJ To be honest I just need a library that lets me add text fields onto the PDF... I could probably send an array of bytes to the backend after. I think the coordinate solution would be a lot of work considering they work differenlty inside a PDF page, and would also need to be transformed as you said.

Comment: @KJ I see what you mean. I wonder if I could wrap a canvas around each PDF page and get the coordinates this way. Haven't seen much online.

Comment: @KJ Thanks for the input! I followed your advice and actually managed to retrieve the coordinates. First I retrieve the canvas DOM element of each page and then, on a canvas click event, I get PDF page height (static) and subtract the canvas Y coordinate. 
This way I can have the coordinate origin at the bottom left of the page. Is there anything else I need to be concerned with or can I send these coordinates to the backend knowing the text fields will get added at the correct location?

Comment: @KJ Currently I have 1:1 scale (so no zoom) and for now rotation and flipping doesn't need to be addressed. Do I need to convert these canvas coordinates to PDF points? If so how, is there a formula?

Comment: @KJ Sorry, can you go through that again? I got a bit lost. Are you saying a pixel is 1/96 of an inch while a PDF unit is 1/72 of an inch?